# PHP - Zend Soap Request to .NET SOAP Server

Tags: php, .net, zend-framework, soap, zend-soap

I'd like a little bit of assistance here.

I am trying to send a request to a .NET SOAP server from PHP with Zend.

I have the WSDL file but it does not contain any header information.
Though I have tried to add a custom header this does not seem to work and the worst is that
the WSDL file itself does not seem to be "right".....

Here is the link: http://www.speedex.gr/getvoutrans/getvoutrans.asmx
The WSDL can be found in the same link by adding ?WSDL

My request is: GetVouTrans

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The http://www.speedex.gr/getvoutrans/getvoutrans.asmx?op=GetVouTrans url shows the expected request.

If you'll overwrite the [SoapClient::__doRequest](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php) function, you can check what you're sending.
*(don't forget to call the parent::__doRequest())*

**You can even change the xml** to make .net specific changes.

To bad SOAP doesn't always work out of the box between different language.
I've had problems with php 5.2.0 (debian) and a java soap-server, the problem disappeared in thin air when i upgraded to php version 5.2.8

A comment on the __doRequest manpage suggests:

```
class MSSoapClient extends SoapClient {

  function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) {
    $namespace = "http://tempuri.com";

    $request = preg_replace('/<ns1:(\w+)/', '<$1 xmlns="'.$namespace.'"', $request, 1);
    $request = preg_replace('/<ns1:(\w+)/', '<$1', $request);
    $request = str_replace(array('/ns1:', 'xmlns:ns1="'.$namespace.'"'), array('/', ''), $request);

    // parent call
    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
  }
}

$client = new MSSoapClient(...);
```

But this comment is from 2007, so your mileage may vary.